# How to create a button that opens a new page with the option to return back to previous page [ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Right below the page you see a '**back to log**' button. If someone clicks on that it will return to the left page. So in order to do so I thought using react router will do the job. But not sure how to fix that.Is there someone who can help me to point me to the right direction. **Keep in mind that it will not open a new tab!**

Link to working snippet to understand the bigger picture of my app. [CodeSandBox snippet here](https://codesandbox.io/s/solitary-framework-ynev2?file=/src/components/Search/SearchInput.tsx)

```js
return (
<div>
    {info.map((show: any) => {
        console.log(show.show)
        return (
            <div key={show.show.id}>
                <ReactMarkdown source={show.show.name}/>

                {show.show.image && <img src={show.show.image.medium}/>}

                {show.show.genres.map((showGenre: string, index: number) => {
                    return (
                        <div key={index}>
                            <ReactMarkdown source={showGenre}/>
                        </div>
                    )
                })}
                <div>
                <Router>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <Link to="/">See deta</Link>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </Router>

                </div>

            </div>
        )
    })}
</div>
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this working example (I placed notes in each file):

https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-panini-hkzlv?file=/src/App.js

Overview:

- there are several ways to do this
- my suggestion is to use the history npm and create a history.js file
- you will also need to use Router from react-router-dom
- in your parent component, or in a Context provider, you can store your state
- in the parent component, use react-router-dom Switch and Route to place routes
- depending on implementation, conditionally render show route for async state update
- in your search component, place all your Links using react-router-dom
- on click Links should also update app's state of your specific selection
- this selection gets passed to the show route/component
- in the show component attach an on click that uses history.goBack and resets state

Comment: Thanks this is a good answer, but forgot to mention that I use it with redux, could you apply redux to this...since it is a small app and dont want to mix it up with usestate and redux.

Comment: @Frontendemployee see updated codesandbox for redux implementation

Comment: Correct now. Also important to mention that history 4.10.0 version is required. Newer version seems not working in my cause.

Comment: This is because history ^5.0.0 is only compatible with React-router-dom ^6.0.0, which is a beta version. If you npm i react-router-dom you are given 5.2.0, so it appears history jumped the gun on its default version.

Comment: Good to know. Could you also secure the link, so user only get access when it clicks on get details button and not via url.....

Comment: Added a useEffect that does that.

Answer (score -1):

this might help you:

```
this.props.history.goBack();
```

it goes back to prev page